# "MOUNT AT STARTUP" HDD ERROR

Tags: 13.10, 64-bit, automount

Primary my disk is ssd (OS, home) and secondary is HDD for data. When I'm trying to made my HDD "MOUNT AT STARTUP", I'm getting error on startup ([see it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEjpI.jpg)) when option is "AUTOMATIC MOUNT OPTION" all is ok, but it isn't mounted on startup until I click on it. I need that it would be mounted on startup cause of I'm getting error of dropbox that cannot find the disk and I need restart the dropbox.

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="37ab3801-11f0-4dcd-b833-f929c21bbea4" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="4f0c58f1-1947-463f-98b4-b3d1c0d0a1fe" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdb1: UUID="669bf7ce-53bd-416e-a708-e4564b60d0cb" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdb5: LABEL="Data" UUID="03654b89-86c0-4fa5-bd35-fa5355695bcb" TYPE="ext4"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add the option to not require the disk to be present at boot with the `noauto` flag.

reference this post: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1803779

The relevant bits:

```
somthing along these lines in the stab would work;

/dev/udev-id /media/extern-drive-noauto ext4 user,noauto 0 0
```

Comment: noauto = No mount at startup. Any advices?

Comment: Ah My mistake, I didn't see that you were intentionally trying to get it to auto-mount on startup. Can you pastebin the contents of your /etc/fstab? (minus anything sensitive if there are network drives in there)

Comment: UUID=37ab3801-11f0-4dcd-b833-f929c21bbea4 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=4f0c58f1-1947-463f-98b4-b3d1c0d0a1fe /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=669bf7ce-53bd-416e-a708-e4564b60d0cb none            swap    sw